# Site needs an "advice" tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I want to ask a question highly related to my path with sports; here it is:

> Am I too old to start playing soccer? I have everything a soccer player has because I have ran and weightlifted my whole life; however, I have only been practicing ball control for a few hours a day by juggling and running with the ball - for only two weeks. So I can tell you I am very fast, I can jump, (I am not too agile however), and I can't dribble.
>
> I am 19 and I am looking to join a league soon. I plan to play on the intramurals for one season, and walk-on to my university's soccer club in fall. I want to practice ball control every day, for at least one hour - by juggling and dribbling the ball. I can do this solo.
>
> My question is, is it realistic to hope one day I can make it to the big leagues? Perhaps start at a club and then the MLS? **How realistic is it?** I am very discouraged (but nevertheless I will keep on practicing) because I know only of soccer players that have practiced since they were young are at the top.

However I don't know if such question is on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Your requests fall under the category of "[primarily opinion-based](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)." Asking us if you're too old to play soccer or how realistic your chances are for making the big leagues is highly opinionated.

Please look at the questions we have and the help center for a better idea of questions that are on-topic on this site. I'm sure you can formulate questions about ball control, juggling and dribbling, and anything related to soccer technique, etc. that are on-topic here.